# A global error handler for a class library in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, class-library

Is there a way to catch and handle an exception for all exceptions thrown within any of the methods of a class library?

I can use a try catch construct within each method as in sample code below, but I was looking for a global error handler for a class library. The library could be used by ASP.Net or Winforms apps or another class library.

The benefit would be easier development, and no need to repeatedly do the same thing within each method.

```
public void RegisterEmployee(int employeeId)
{
   try
   {
     ....
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
     ABC.Logger.Log(ex);
   throw;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use ContextBoundObject

Comment: Can you share some sample code, but only if you have it? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subscribe to global event handler like `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and check the method that throws exception:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException;

private static void CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs unhandledExceptionEventArgs)
{
    var exceptionObject = unhandledExceptionEventArgs.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    if (exceptionObject == null) return;
    var assembly = exceptionObject.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Assembly;
    if (assembly == //your code)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious. Would this involve reflection when getting exceptionObject.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Assembly?

Comment: The `TargetSite` property returns the method of `MethodBase` type  that throws the current exception. The `MethodBase` type is a part of reflection library and it follows that the reflection will be used.