# Log4Net: logging all unhandled exceptions in C# class library project

Tags: c#, exception, logging, log4net, unhandled

I have a C# class library project and I need to capture all unhandled exceptions in my class even if I not use try catch blocks.
Note: I have already  installed log4net with log4net.config and it works fine logging manually in Debug,Info,Error.

Can you help me?

thanks

Comment: what type of technology your are using ? for example if asp.net you can put in application_error in global.asax.

Comment: Check this  global error handler: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872620/a-global-error-handler-for-a-class-library-in-c-sharp

Comment: I'm using asp.net c# class library project and I don't have global.asax file in my project. Can I add it if I'm not in web context?

Comment: @HanyHabib I'm using asp.net c# class library project and I don't have global.asax file in my project. Can I add it if I'm not in web context?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A global error handler for a class library in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872620/a-global-error-handler-for-a-class-library-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @DavidKemp It's a dll library project and I don't have main class to put handler inside it. how can I do ?

Comment: I'd argue exception handling is not your problem - I don't expect Microsoft's assemblies to log all the exceptions they handle. Log *why* the exception is thrown if you throw it - that's far more useful than just knowing an exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076063/how-to-log-all-thrown-exceptions) was helpful.
The only downside to this is that you may end up logging too many exceptions. Since you say you are writing a class library, depending on the application that will use your library, you may not want to catch all the exceptions thrown by the application. To solve this issue, I recommend doing something like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.Exception.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Assembly == Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    {
        logger.ErrorFormat("Exception Thrown: {0}\n{1}", e.Exception.Message, e.Exception.StackTrace);
    }
};
```

This way, you will only catch exceptions from your code. Hope this helps !