# C# Catch all exception witin all methods within one class

Tags: c#

I developed a Outlook addin. this addin gets unregistered when it throws an exception. What I rather would like to achieve is to catch all exceptions of my class and log this exception in order to analyse this. Do I need to add a try / catch in all methods or is there another method?

Comment: You can catch exception, log and rethrow (in every public member), but an easier way is to add handler for [unhandled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17872620/1997232)

Answer (score 0):

I have never developed an addin, so this is just a guess, but you could write an abstraction layer that serves as a "meta-addin" which handles the exceptions.

So you create a new class and override all the functions you need and add try-catch blocks in all of them. In them, you call the actual functions that contain your code. That way, you can at least re-use the exception functionality across multiple addins.